# How do I get HTML 5 video player to play my video on PC Firefox?

Tags: firefox, video, html5-video, m4v, video.js

I'm using Win XP, service pack 3.  I have an M4V video that I'm trying to embed in a web page using the HTML 5 video player found here -- http://videojs.com/.  When I view this page through Apache 2.2, the video plays fine on Chrome and IE 7, but not on Firefox (just a black square without video controls) ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/video.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
  preload="auto" width="960" height="540" poster="css/video-js.png"
  data-setup="{}">
  <source src="videos/unpacking_w_students.m4v" type='video/m4v'>
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what may be going wrong?  If there were some additional things I could add to the web page to help Firefox play it, that would be ideal, but if there is some other setting to adjust, that would be great to know as well.

Answer (score 1):

Video.js should fall back to Flash when only using an mp4/m4v in Firefox, just like it does in IE7. Might be a dumb question, but do you have Flash installed in Firefox?

Otherwise, is it throwing any errors in the JavaScript console, or is there a live page we can look at?

Comment: Also, check your network log and make sure Firefox is requesting and successfully loading the VideoJS .swf file.

Answer (score 0):

You're only sending H.264 data.

Firefox doesn't have a patent license to ship an H.264 decoder, so it does not support that video format.  It does support Theora and VP8.

Comment: But I am able to see the above play fine on Mac Firefox.  Also, if I open up the file on PC firefox (just File -> Open -> myfile.m4v), it plays fine.  Doesn't that put a wrench in your theory?

Comment: If you just open the file, it's probably getting rendered by a plug-in, not by the browser itself.  As far as on Mac... that's incredibly odd.  Can you link to a page showing that behavior?